# How to print Json result to view in angular js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, angularjs

Hello I am new to angular js , I need some help that  i have one edit form in angular js when user click on edit it redirect to edit form but i am getting some issues that my json result look like  :

```
    [{"0":"3",
      "1":"The only people for me are the mad ones",
      "2":"“The only people for me are the mad ones, the ones who are mad to live, mad to talk, mad to be saved, desirous of everything at the same time, the ones who never yawn or say a commonplace thing, but burn, burn, burn like fabulous yellow roman candles exploding like spiders across the stars.”",
      "3":"2015-05-08 13:01:58",
      "id":"3","title":"The only people for me are the mad ones",
      "description":"“The only people for me are the mad ones, the ones who are mad to live, mad to talk, mad to be saved, desirous of everything at the same time, the ones who never yawn or say a commonplace thing, but burn, burn, burn like fabulous yellow roman candles exploding like spiders across the stars.”",
      "created_on":"2015-05-08 13:01:58"
}]
```

I want to know how to print my title , description in view.

Here is my controller file: where i get the data from database:

```
 var myApp = angular.module("blogapp",[]);

  myApp.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider
      .when('/home',{
        templateUrl:'home.html',
        controller:'blogcontroller'
      })
      .when('/list',{
        templateUrl:'list.html',
        controller:'blogcontroller'

      })
      .when('/add',{

        templateUrl:'add.html',
        controller:'addcontroller'
      })
      .when('/edit/:Blogid',{

        templateUrl:'edit.html',
        controller:'editcontroller'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo:'/home'
      });

  }]);


myApp.controller('blogcontroller',function ($scope,$http){

    $http({method: 'GET' , url: 'getallblog.php'}).success(function(data){
      $scope.allblog = data;

      console.log(data);
    });

// DELETE blog HERE 
 $scope.removeRow= function(id){



    $http.post("removeblog.php",{'id' : id}).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
      window.location='index.html';
      console.log("Deleted Successfully");

  });
  };

// delete blog code ends here


  });


myApp.controller('addcontroller',function ($scope,$http){





  /// New Post Here
    $scope.new_post =function(){



    $http.post("addblog.php" ,{'title' : $scope.title ,'description' : $scope.description }).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
      window.location='index.html';
      console.log("inserted Successfully");
    });
  };



  // New Post ends Here

});

myApp.controller('editcontroller',function ($scope,$http,$routeParams){

     $scope.Blogid = $routeParams.Blogid;

     $http.post("getblog.php",{'id' : $scope.Blogid}).success(function(data){
      $scope.editit = data;  /// here i get the resuly  want to pass it t view

      console.log(data);

  });


});
```

My edit html form : edit.html

```
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <!-- Blog Entries Column -->
            <div class="col-md-6">

                <h1 class="page-header">
                   Angular Blog 

                </h1>


               <div >

        <form class="form-signin">


        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Modify // want to print title here </h2>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <label for="posttitle" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="text" id="posttitle" class="form-control" ng-model="{{title}}"  required="" value=""><br>
        <span>Title : // want to print title here</span>
        </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <label for="postdetails" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <textarea id="postdetails" class="form-control" ng-model="description" required=""></textarea>
        <br>
        <span>Blog Description: // want to print description here</span>
        </div>
       </div>
       <br>
       <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3"></div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button" ng-click="edit_post()" name="editblog">Modify Now</button>
        </div>
              <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>

      </form>

      </div>

            </div>
             <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <!-- Blog Sidebar Widgets Column -->
             <div ng-include="'includes/sidebar.html'">                    
</div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->



    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to print your title, you first need  to  replace this  line in JS:

```
  $scope.allblog = data;
```

with

```
  $scope.allblog = data[0];
```

Now,  you can write in HTML the following statement:

```
{{allblog.title}}
```

Comment: One more thing i want to print title in textbox for edit , its

 <input type="text" id="posttitle" class="form-control" ng-model="title"  required="" value="{{editblog.title}}" > its not show anything in textbox

Comment: <input type="text" id="posttitle" class="form-control" ng-model="{{editblog.title}}" required="">

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
        <span>Blog Description: {{allblog.description}}</span>
```

Or

```
<span>Blog Description: <span ng-bind-html ="allblog.description"></span></span>
```

if your allblog is an array use allblog[0]

Comment: why you need `ng-bind-html`?

Comment: to not show {{allblog.description}} while page before evaluating it. ng-bind-html  will not show until interpolcation is done

Comment: Could you add this to your html and tell me what is the result? <pre> blogs : {{allblog | json }}</pre>